# Prevent command line tool (hrping) from opening new window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

There is an excellent command line utility for windows called hrping (high resolution ping) that times the round trip for pings in microseconds.  It runs under Windows 7 but has the annoying behavior of popping up a UAC alert when starting and opening in a new window.  Is there anything I can do to get this program to run in the current window so its output is not lost?  Thanks.  -- Bud

Comment: Humm.  I just tried it on Windows 7 Home premium in a "administrator" command prompt and it works fine.  Not sure why it is different on Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `runas /user:administrator hrping`?
It should prompt for a password in the shell, hopefully bypassing a graphical display.